# Can we determine the existence of real solutions of a sixth order polynomial?

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson

I am developing an algorithm. In the algorithm, I look for the real root of a sixth order polynomial. In the code, I used Newton's method to find the roots. I try to limit the roots, (because Newton's depends on the initial point) this makes the method very expensive. Do you suggest any other method which is cheaper than Newton? Do you know a good way to find suitable initial point for Newton?

Comment: See [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20946/criteria-to-determine-whether-a-real-coefficient-polynomial-has-real-root).

Comment: See also [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_.28complex.29_polynomial_roots) about finding bounds for roots (bounds for complex roots also apply to real roots). An average of the upper and lower bounds will probably be not-too-bad of a starting point. (Though because the bounds are on the absolute values, this actually defines two intervals, symmetric about 0, that the roots can be in. So you will want to determine if you are after positive or negative roots, per Dietrich Burde's link, first.)